# Table class not working after append in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am working with ajax and jquery,Actually i am using two different functions

1. Append class name"active" to columns(which clicked)
2. Run Ajax after every 10 seconds
   So my first function working correctly and append class to columns(append class in "name" or "symbol" column/table header),But whenever i use 2nd function then getting old "class text" but in inspect element
   showing "active" to another,How can i do this ?

Here is my html code

```
<table border='1' width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;' id='postsList'>
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>S.no</th>
        <th class="column_sort" id="name" data-order="desc" href="#">Title
        </th>
        <th class="column_sort" id="symbol" data-order="desc" href="#">Symbol
        </th>
    </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my First function which appending class to columns(dynamic)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timesClicked = 0;
  $(document).on('click', '.column_sort', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var PageNumber = $("#pagination").find("strong").html();
    $(".column_sort").removeClass("active");
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?=base_url()?>/Main/fetch_details/',
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        column_name: column_name,
        PageNumber: PageNumber
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#postsList tr:not(:first)").remove();
        $("#postsList2").show();
        $("#postsList2").html(data);
        $('#' + column_name + '').addClass('active');
        return false;
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Here is my second function,Where i am wrong ?

```
setInterval(UpdateAllListing, 10000);

function UpdateAllListing() {
  if ($('th.column_sort').hasClass('active')) {
    var ColumnName = $('th.column_sort').text();
    alert(ColumnName)
  } else {
    alert(ColumnName);
  }
  //ajax code here
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve with the UpdateAllListing function...can you explain it better please? It seems it doesn't do what you wanted, but from your description I cannot understand exactly what you wanted it to do.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML markup it is hard to do a proper analysis. But what I see is, that you remove class `active` from elements selected by `$(".column_sort")`, which you then check in function `UpdateAllListing()` by using a similar selector. Are you sure that the cell element by ID `column_name` refers to a `th` element which would match selector `th.column_sort`? Or: Is there an element `<th id="..." class="column_sort">` in your markup?

Comment: @ADyson let me explain, I have two table header "name" and "symbol"
And whenever i click on any icon(among these two) then i am appending "active" class This is first step, And i am facing problem in second step , Problem is .....after click on other icon again using ajax ...i am getting class.text of previous icon ( means for example i click on "symbol" but showing me text value of "name" instead of symbol), Hope you understand my point

Comment: `after click on other icon again using ajax`...sorry but what do you mean by this really? You can't use AJAX to click on things. Please try to describe what you mean in a better way. As majusebetter said, this would probably a lot easier to understand if you show us the HTML this code is trying to work with.

Comment: But what I can observe is that `$('th.column_sort').text()` will just select the text of the first item which has the "th.column_sort" class. If you have more than one item with that class it will just always get the first one. Are you really wanting to get the one which has the "active" class? It's not clear if you added the "active" class to that element or another one, though - again, we really need to see your HTML.

Comment: @ADyson: you are right and going to edit my question ( adding html )

Comment: @ADyson: Edited my question,Now you can see my html also

Comment: Ok thanks. So if you click "Symbol" it would add `active` class to the `<th class="column_sort" id="symbol" data-order="desc" href="#">` element, is that correct? We actually cannot see from your code how you are populating the `column_name` variable, so we cannot tell what exactly the line `$('#' + column_name + '').addClass('active')` will do.

Comment: P.S. As an aside, the ` + ''` in `$('#' + column_name + '')` is completely pointless. `$('#' + column_name)` would produce the exact same result.

Comment: @ADyson: actually class appending properly(add and remove ) but i am facing problem whenever i get class.text....showing me same value again and again but in inspect element class appending correctly

Comment: @ADyson: what should i replace with "+" sign

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. I showed you a simpler way to do it already, but that is just a minor point.

Comment: What's more important is telling us where `column_name` gets its value from

Comment: @ADyson: I am using following line for this


var column_name = $(this).attr("id");

Comment: Ok thanks. Why is that not shown in your question? It should be within the click event, I would have expected? But yes that then means that `var ColumnName = $('th.column_sort.active').text()` would make more sense in your other function. It should then select only the item which currently has the "active" class.

Comment: I've not waded through the comments, but this line `.hasClass('active')` will trigger if any of them have `active` class but this line `$('th.column_sort').text();` will only affect the *first* column regardless of which is active - probably should be `$('th.column_sort.active').text();`